# Are there any NFC tags that act as a switch or relay?

Tags: switches, relay, nfc

From what I understand there is always an active (reader/writer) and a passive (tag) NFC device.

Is it possible to have an NFC tag which is part of a circuit and works as a switch or a relay?

I would like to have a reader read the tag and if some condition is fullfilled the reader would then "tell" the tag to switch the circuit on or off. Is this possible?

Comment: yes ... anything is possible

Comment: Do you have any links to existing devices or something like that please? I could not find anything so far.

Comment: no, I do not ... you asked a question that has a `yes/no` answer ... `no` is not really a choice because you are asking about communication between two electronic devices, and that is done every day ... therefore, the only possible answer is `yes`

Comment: you would have to design and build the tag device

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nfc does not require the tag to be passive. Active tags exist. A NFC tag is essentially just an eeprom or microcontroller that can pick up modulated signal over RF, and optionally be powered by the low powered NFC rf signal.

You can do this by either using an eeprom based nfc tag that provides the eeprom over say i2c, or a microcontroller that emulates as a tag. Once the nfc writer writes a specific code to the eeprom/microcontroller, your circuit reads it and does whatever you want. Then you erase the code/value/registry to do it again later.

Like https://www.st.com/en/nfc/m24lr04e-r.html or https://hackaday.com/2020/01/30/nfc-for-your-home-automation/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like NXP has released a newish tag called NTAG® 5 Switch: NFC Forum-Compliant PWM GPIO Bridge for Lighting and Gaming has GPIO output that can control stuff like mosfets etc...

Unsure if the setting is persistent if externally powered and would thus not require NFC harvested power.

https://www.nxp.com/products/rfid-nfc/nfc-hf/connected-nfc-tags/ntag-5-switch-nfc-forum-compliant-pwm-gpio-bridge-for-lighting-and-gaming:NTAG5-SWITCH